# Document Data Source property changes type/class in nested Custom Controls

Tags: javascript, data-binding, xpages

Here's part of our internal log, where I print the compositeData for 2 different custom controls, one the caller and the 2nd one the callee, in both cases during the BeforePageLoad event.

The parameter dataSource is passed "as-is", using

```
dataSource="#{javascript:compositeData.dataSource}
```

**The log**

14:37:29.876 {dataSource=com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument@379c379c, dataSource2=com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument@379c379c}

14:37:29.894 {dataSource=com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding@31433143, dataSource2=com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding@32613261}

For some reason, in the 2nd custom control (called by the 1st one), dataSource gets lost and becomes completely useless.

**Question**

How can it happen that a binding suddenly changes type, i.e. from a wrapped DominoDocument to a JavaScriptValueBinding ?? And what can I do about it??

*PS dataSource2 was a feeble attempt to pass a 2nd parameter all the way down from the top, bound to the same wrapped NotesDocument.*

**Ugly work-around**

Instead of properly passing the document through a parameter, I now use the original NotesDocument as declared in the main page. We needed this quick fix in order to continue, but I'd love to have an explanation for this bug (XPages or mine?) and the correct way to handle parameter passing.

Answer (score 2):

It does work well in my simple example:

Main XPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="document1"
            formName="Test">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xc:datasource1
        dataSource="#{document1}" />
</xp:view>
```

Custom Control "datasource1" (first level)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    beforePageLoad="#{javascript:print('1: ' + compositeData.dataSource)}">
    datasource1
    <xp:br />
    <xc:datasource2
        dataSource="#{compositeData.dataSource}" />
</xp:view>
```

Custom Control "datasource2" (second level)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    beforePageLoad="#{javascript:print('2: ' + compositeData.dataSource)}">
    dataSource2
</xp:view>
```

The output on server console shows correct DominoDocument type for both levels

```
HTTP JVM: 1: com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument@7ee27ee2
HTTP JVM: 2: com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument@7ee27ee2
```

It doesn't matter how you define "datasource" property type  - it does work with type "string" and with "com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData".

Maybe, you can go from this example and figure out what's different in your code.

Comment: I know, I use it all the time... But suddenly, when dataSource is passed several times to nested controls, it changes type. For me, it's Page->MyForm->MyFlatForm->MySubForm->MyField, and there it's gone. I also have elements like Page->MyForm->MyFlatForm->MyField, i.e. a MyForm contains both MyField and MySubForm controls.

Comment: I tried it with five nested custom controls now mixed with different levels: still the same - it works. Can you create an example where that issue happens?

Answer (score 0):

Works as designed. One is passing the parameter as a static value, the other is computing the parameter.

Instead of trying to pass the whole document, try to pass the binding string. This makes it more flexible since you can change your mind on what to bind to (bean, scope, object etc).